# Does IE9 support input type="file" multiple="multiple"?

Tags: html

Already checked the Internet but I wasn't able to find it out :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_layout_engines_%28HTML5%29) (see "Form elements and attributes"), no.